# Voltage limiter

Tags: circuit-design

I am trying to make a voltage limiter circuit using a Zener diode. I don't want a fixed output, but I want to make something with a variable output between 0V to 1.5V. I know a Zener diode will limit the output to the voltage the diode is rated at, but what happens if I supply voltage lower than what the Zener diode is rated at?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you want to do with voltage after it has been "limited?"  Why do you need it limited?

Comment: If you supply a voltage lower than the Zener diode's voltage, it won't conduct.

Comment: If the voltage does not exceed the zener voltage, it can't clamp it.

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I think you've converted a valid answer into a comment. It's terse but it does answer the question. If the OP doesn't understand the answer s/he can comment on it for clarification.

Comment: Whatever OP is doing, it's probably better done with something other than a zener.   OP, be more clear what your intentions are.  What is your driving voltage source, what's the load, etc...   ???

Comment: @JRE Trying to make a electric scooter. This is for the throttle signal and supply voltage is 5v but what I am trying to do is slow the speed of the wheel down even if the throttle is pressed all the way. I would like it to limit it at around 1.8v. I am not sure how much current it's drawing but I know it is very little. I will measure the current that way I know exactly how much current draw.

Comment: @surajkc: Edit that into your question, along with a drawing of the circuit you are trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the circuit below.  If the supply voltage is below the Zener voltage, all voltage will be across the Zener (2V) and no voltage across the 100 ohm resistor (0V.)

[image]

Here is a circuit that can control the voltage across the load in your desired range (approximatelly 0 - 1.8V) with potentiometer R3. The low voltage Zeners are not sufficient as voltage references due to their poor characteristics so rather to use higher voltage zener (3V6 or  more) and obtain the desired voltage level with a divider.

Since you didn't mention the power draw, this circuit works up to 20mA. You can increase it by lowering the resistances to ensure enough Q1 base current.

[image]